# Unable to display data fetched from the database

Tags: database, jsf

I am new to stackoverflow and to Java. I am trying to fetch the data from the database then display it in a JSF page.
For the table I have a model : BusesInfo.java that contains getters and setters for the attributes of the table.
then I also have BusesDao that fetches the data from DB and stores it in an array list. BusesInfoBean that links these data to the JSF page. The connection to the database is success. the JSF page contains a table that calls BusesInfobean.busesInfo  in the columns i call BusesInfo.attribute
Please I need your help! Below you can find sample codes:

```
package beans;

import daos.BusesDao;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import models.BusesInfo;

@ViewScoped
public class BusesInfoBean implements Serializable {

private final BusesDao busesDao = new BusesDao();
private ArrayList<BusesInfo> busesInfo; 



 public BusesInfoBean(){}

    @PostConstruct
public void init(){
    try {            
        busesInfo = busesDao.buildBusesInfo();            
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ManageEventsBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public ArrayList<BusesInfo> getBusesInfo() {
    return busesInfo;
}

public void setBusesInfo(ArrayList<BusesInfo> busesInfo) {
    this.busesInfo = busesInfo;
}

}
```

BusesDao.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import models.BusesInfo;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.Level;

public class BusesDao extends ConnectionDao {


    public ArrayList<BusesInfo> buildBusesInfo() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<BusesInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Connection conn = getConnection();

    try {            
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM BUSES_INFO";                        
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);            

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();           

        while (rs.next()) {
            list.add(populateBusesInfo(rs));
        }

        rs.close();
        ps.close();

        return list;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
    }
}

    private BusesInfo populateBusesInfo(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    BusesInfo busesInfo = new BusesInfo();

    busesInfo.setBusID(rs.getInt("BUS_ID"));
    busesInfo.setDriverID(rs.getInt("DRIVER_ID"));
    busesInfo.setDepartureTime(rs.getString("DEPARTURE_TIME"));                    
    busesInfo.setArrivalTime(rs.getString("ARRIVAL_TIME"));                    
    busesInfo.setRouteEn(rs.getString("ROUTE_EN"));                    
    busesInfo.setRouteAr(rs.getString("ROUTE_AR"));                    
    busesInfo.setLicensePlate(rs.getString("LICENSE_PLATE")); 
    busesInfo.setCapacity(rs.getInt("CAPACITY"));
    return busesInfo;
}

public static void main(String [] args){        
    try {
        BusesDao busesDao = new BusesDao();                
        ArrayList<BusesInfo> busesInfo = busesDao.buildBusesInfo();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EventsDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

}
```

the model class BusesInfo only contains getters and setters:

```
public class BusesInfo implements Serializable {

private int busID;
private int driverID;
private String departureTime;
private String arrivalTime;
private String routeEn;
private String routeAr;
private String licensePlate;
private int capacity;

public BusesInfo(){}
/**
 *
 * @param busID
 * @param driverID
 * @param departureTime
 * @param arrivalTime
 * @param routeEn
 * @param routeAr
 * @param licensePlate
 * @param capacity
 */
public BusesInfo(int busID, int driverID, String departureTime, String arrivalTime, String routeEn, String routeAr, String licensePlate, int capacity) {
    this.busID = busID;
    this.driverID = driverID;
    this.departureTime = departureTime;
    this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
    this.routeEn = routeEn;
    this.routeAr = routeAr;
    this.licensePlate = licensePlate;
    this.capacity = capacity;
}

public int getBusID() {
    return busID;
}

public void setBusID(int busID) {
    this.busID = busID;
}

public int getDriverID() {
    return driverID;
}

public void setDriverID(int driverID) {
    this.driverID = driverID;
}

public String getDepartureTime() {
    return departureTime;
}

public void setDepartureTime(String departureTime) {
    this.departureTime = departureTime;
}

public String getArrivalTime() {
    return arrivalTime;
}

public void setArrivalTime(String arrivalTime) {
    this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
}

public String getRouteEn() {
    return routeEn;
}

public void setRouteEn(String routeEn) {
    this.routeEn = routeEn;
}

public String getRouteAr() {
    return routeAr;
}

public void setRouteAr(String routeAr) {
    this.routeAr = routeAr;
}

public String getLicensePlate() {
    return licensePlate;
}

public void setLicensePlate(String licensePlate) {
    this.licensePlate = licensePlate;
}

public int getCapacity() {
    return capacity;
}

public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
}

}
```

JSF page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>#{msgs.buses}</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div>
        <ui:decorate template="/app_templates/app_template.xhtml">
            <h:form id="bus_info_form">
                <p:dataTable 
                       id="bus_info_tbl"
                       value = "#{busesInfoBean.busesInfo}"
                       class = "dataTable"
                       var="event"
                       rows="2"
                       dir="#{langBean.dir}"
                       emptyMessage="#{msgs.no_buses}"
                       paginator="true"
                       paginatorPosition="top" 
                       paginatorTemplate="#{langBean.isEnglish? '{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}' : '{RowsPerPageDropdown} {LastPageLink} {NextPageLink} {PageLinks} {PreviousPageLink} {FirstPageLink}'}"
                         >
                        <p:ajax event="rowSelectRadio"
                          update=":bus_info_form:bus_info_tbl"/>  

                        <f:facet name="header" id="header">
                            #{msgs.buses}
                        </f:facet> 

                        <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:5%"/>

                        <p:column headerText="#{msgs.bus_id}"
                                  style="width:15%"
                                  sortBy="#{busesInfo.busID}">                    
                            <h:outputText value="#{busesInfo.busID}"/>  
                        </p:column>

                         <p:column headerText="#{msgs.driver_id}"
                                  style="width:15%"
                                  sortBy="#{busesInfo.driverID}">                    
                            <h:outputText value="#{busesInfo.driverID}"/>  
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="#{msgs.departure_time}"
                                  style="width:15%"
                                  sortBy="#{busesInfo.departureTime}">                    
                            <h:outputText value="#{busesInfo.departureTime}"/>  
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="#{msgs.arrival_time}"
                                  style="width:15%"
                                  sortBy="#{busesInfo.arrivalTime}">                    
                            <h:outputText value="#{busesInfo.arrivalTime}"/>  
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="#{msgs.route}"
                            style="width:20%"
                            filterBy="#{langBean.isEnglish?busesInfo.routeEn:busesInfo.routeAr}"
                            filterMatchMode="contains"
                            sortBy="#{langBean.isEnglish?busesInfo.routeEn:busesInfo.routeAr}">                    
                          <h:outputText value="#{langBean.isEnglish?busesInfo.routeEn:busesInfo.routeAr}"/>  
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="#{msgs.license_plate}"
                                  style="width:15%"
                                  sortBy="#{busesInfo.licensePlate}">                    
                            <h:outputText value="#{busesInfo.licensePlate}"/>  
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="#{msgs.capacity}"
                                  style="width:15%"
                                  sortBy="#{busesInfo.capacity}">                    
                            <h:outputText value="#{busesInfo.capacity}"/>  
                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>

        </ui:decorate>

    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @SilverNak there is no syntax errors but the data arent displayed. maybe they are not fetched properly. However the table names are correct. I just can not find where is the problem. Maybe the arraylist is not saving the attributes. I tried to debug the code but debugging didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you please show your JSF-Code?

Comment: Please start by narrowing down the problem. Can you retrieve the data from the database? Then it is most likely not database related. Can you display a static array? Then it is not JSF related. 99.9% of the questions that people tag both database and jsf are only related to one of them. That is something you could (should) find out yourself. Creating a [mcve] always helps in this regard. And use more modern tutorials. Doing jdbc in a jsf managed bean was from the start a bad design. Check http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info for good tutorials!

Comment: @SilverNak sure I added it. the text i get is the same text i assigned in emptyMessage (in the table tag).

Comment: And start by using CDI instead of JSF managed beans... (what tutorial DID you use btw?)

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for the advises. I have followed university lectures. My instructor asked me to do it this as it is consistent with the rest of the project.